# Enforcing unique constraint based on foreign key

Tags: python, django

I enforced a unique constraint for a column and since the constraint is enforced on the entire table, is there a way to make a column unique based on the foreign key?

#### Models

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    """This class represents the bucket model"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)

class Bucketlist(models.Model):
    """This class represents the bucketlists model"""
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
             related_name='bucketlists')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
```

E.g
I created 2 buckets (bucket 1 and bucket 2)

Created the following bucketlists

```
>>> Bucketlist.objects.create(bucket=bucket1, name='bucketlist1')
>>> Bucketlist.objects.create(bucket=bucket1, name='bucketlist2')
```

Attempting to create bucketlist1 in bucket 2

```
>>> Bucketlist.objects.create(bucket=bucket2, name='bucketlist1')
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_bucketlist_name"
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking here. What is the unique field you are referring to (you have two unique fields in the models above)? And what field is `bucketlist1` the value for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the `name` field on `Bucketlist` to be unique, but only for those objects who belong to the same `Bucket`.

For this you can look at Django's `unique_together` Meta option ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together)).

In your case it would look like:

```
class Bucketlist(models.Model):
    """This class represents the bucketlists model"""
    bucket = models.ForeignKey(Bucket, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                               related_name='bucketlists')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("bucket", "name"),)
```

Notice the removal of `unique=True` from the `name` field.